# Multidimensional Array to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following controller method

```
    public ActionResult Export(string [,] data, string workbookName)
    {
        ExcelWorkbook workbook = new ExcelWorkbook();
        workbook.AddRows(data);

        return new FileStreamResult(workbook.SaveSheet(), "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        {
            FileDownloadName = workbookName
        };
    }
```

Which takes a two dimensional array and outputs to a worksheet.

I have failed so far to get anything other than null in the data parameter when posting from jquery with a json array. Does anyone know the correct format of the json needed to populate the data parameter. I am on Jquery 1.7.2.

Here is my jquery

```
    var arguments = {};

    arguments.data = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"]];
    arguments.workbookName = "test";

    //Populate arrayOfValues 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Excel/Export',
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: arguments,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `datatype` (I think it should be `dataType`) is the type of the *response*, not the request.  I don't think this affects you, but the `arguments` variable looks fine to me.  Are you sure you don't mean for `arguments.data` to be `["1", "2", "3"]`?  What is the server side language?

Comment: The server side language is C#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be better off using a jagged array instead of a multi-dimensional array.  I have had more success getting a jagged array working.  Also Explosion Pills is right, the dataType is the type of the response.  I was able to get this working using a json request by using `JSON.stringify` on the data and specifying the contentType of `application\json`:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Test(string[][] fields, string workbookName)
    {
        var cr = new JsonResult();
        cr.Data = fields;
        return cr;
    }
```

JS:

```
var arguments = {};

arguments.fields = new Array(3);
arguments.fields[0] = new Array(3);
arguments.fields[1] = new Array(3);
arguments.fields[2] = new Array(3);

arguments.fields[0][0] = "hello";

arguments.workbookName = "test";

//Populate arrayOfValues 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/Test',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    traditional: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(arguments),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John, this worked a treat. I changed it to the jagged array instead. Si